# how to make a group from different columns based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this :

```
    Air-line        City        Time        ID

0   easyJet         London      20:40       1
1   airberlin       Berlin      10:30       2
2   Emarite         Dubai       21:45       3
3   Qatar Airways   Newyork     10:30       4
4   easyJet         London      20:46       5
5   airberlin       Berlin      10:34       6
.
.
.
.
99   Qatar Airways   London      20:40     13
100   airberlin    Berlin        10:32     20
```

What I want to do is that I use groupby and make a group from columns 'Air-lines', 'City' and 'Time' based on columns ID to change the value in columns ID. So the rows which have same value in Air-line, City and Time should have the same ID. For that I have the following code :

```
df['ID'] = df.groupby(['Air-line','City','Time'])['ID'].transform('first')
```

But the problem is that I want to change the code so that not just the exact value in column 'Time' but also the values which the difference is between +6 or -6 minute should be included as well.

what I expect is this :

```
    Air-line        City        Time        ID

0   easyJet         London      20:40       1
1   airberlin       Berlin      10:30       2
2   Emarite         Dubai       21:45       3
3   Qatar Airways   Newyork     10:30       4
4   easyJet         London      20:46       1
5   airberlin       Berlin      10:34       2
.
.
.
.
99   Qatar Airways   London      20:40       13
100   airberlin    Berlin         10:32       2
```

Could you tell me how can I add this condition? Any help will be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: consider making Time column categorical with a 6 min step.  Then grouping will work as expected.

Comment: @MaximIvanov  Could you tell me which function should I use for that? I'm not very familiar with pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can categorize the `time` column with a 6 min step as shown below.
I use here `pandas.cut` function.
As `bins` I pass a range of datetime objects retrieved from `pd.date_range`.
In `pd.cut` I use `right=False` to include points on the left side on the interval and exclude those on the right side of the interval.

I used a small dataframe as an example, but you will get the idea.

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['20:30', '20:33', '20:36', '20:40', '20:42'],
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

start = df['time'].min()
end = df['time'].max() + pd.Timedelta('6min')
bins = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='6T')

cut = pd.cut(df['time'], bins=bins, right=False)
df['time_category'] = cut

df['ID'] = df.groupby('time_category')['ID'].transform('first')

print(df)
```

Output

```
                 time  ID                               time_category
0 2021-02-03 20:30:00   1  [2021-02-03 20:30:00, 2021-02-03 20:36:00)
1 2021-02-03 20:33:00   1  [2021-02-03 20:30:00, 2021-02-03 20:36:00)
2 2021-02-03 20:36:00   3  [2021-02-03 20:36:00, 2021-02-03 20:42:00)
3 2021-02-03 20:40:00   3  [2021-02-03 20:36:00, 2021-02-03 20:42:00)
4 2021-02-03 20:42:00   5  [2021-02-03 20:42:00, 2021-02-03 20:48:00)
```

### Binning without dates

There is another approach as well.
You mentioned that you need to avoid using dates in grouping.
Unfortunately, I did not manage to extend the solution using pandas internals.
But this can be accomplished in another way.

Let us create `bins` manually from 00:00 to 23:54 and assign keys to each of them.
Then we will use a `categorize` function to assign the corresponding key to the time value.
Note that here I create `new_time` column, which utilizes `time.strptime` conversion.
It is this column, which I then categorize.

```
import itertools
from functools import partial
import time

import pandas as pd

bins = [
    time.strptime(f'{hour}:{minute}', '%H:%M')
    for hour, minute in itertools.product(range(24), range(0, 60, 6))
]

bins_mapping = {
    index: value
    for index, value in enumerate(sorted(bins))
}


def categorize(t, bins_mapping):
    for index, value in bins_mapping.items():
        if value > t:
            break
    return index


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['20:30', '20:33', '20:36', '20:40', '20:42'],
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
})

df['new_time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%H:%M'))
df['time_category'] = df['new_time'].apply(
    partial(categorize, bins_mapping=bins_mapping)
)
df['ID'] = df.groupby('time_category')['ID'].transform('first')

print(df)
```

Output

```
    time  ID                           new_time  time_category
0  20:30   1  (1900, 1, 1, 20, 30, 0, 0, 1, -1)            206
1  20:33   1  (1900, 1, 1, 20, 33, 0, 0, 1, -1)            206
2  20:36   3  (1900, 1, 1, 20, 36, 0, 0, 1, -1)            207
3  20:40   3  (1900, 1, 1, 20, 40, 0, 0, 1, -1)            207
4  20:42   5  (1900, 1, 1, 20, 42, 0, 0, 1, -1)            208
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still don't get start and end. Can I use bins without start and end ?@MaximIvanov

Comment: @lerner12 You can define start and end based on your data in ``time`` column. In this case ``start`` will correspond to the minimum of ``time``, while ``end`` - maximum.

Comment: @lerner12 I provided a more automated example. Please check this.

Comment: @lerner12 Can you confirm if the answer helped you?

Comment: @ Maxim Ivanov I'm trying to adjust it to my data. The problem is that time column in my data should be just time without date and this way I cant use start and end like you did here.

Comment: @ Maxim Ivanov  if I use date as well, then I cant use groupby because the date will most of the time be different although time will be the same. I add .dt.time to pd.to_datetime(df['time']) and have just the time but now it is not working with this code.

Comment: @ Maxim Ivanov could you tell me how I can use only time ?

Comment: @lerner12 I added another approach, which gets rid of dates and deals with time only.